# Rails 4, validate the presence of a nested object on sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I'm trying to add a validation which requires a user to add at least 1 address upon sign up. Each address the user adds creates a new address object. Presently, this is what my user model looks:

`all_blank` isn't even being called when I submit the form, and the validate do block that calls `check_addresses_number`, just returns false every time, because it seems the address objects haven't been created yet.

require 'teamsnap'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ADDRESSES_COUNT_MIN = 1
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_reader :client
    attr_accessor :addresses_attributes

    has_many :carpools, foreign_key: "manager_id"
    has_many :events, foreign_key: "driver_id"
    has_many :events, foreign_key: "swap_requester_id"

    # TODO Differentiate between 'sent invites' and 'invitations'?
    has_many :invites, foreign_key: "sender_id"

    has_many :carpool_memberships, foreign_key: "member_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :carpools, through: :carpool_memberships

    has_many :team_memberships, foreign_key: "member_id"
    has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships

    has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

    validate do
        check_addresses_number
    end


    private

        def all_blank(attributes)
            byebug
        end


        def addresses_count_valid?
            addresses.count >= ADDRESSES_COUNT_MIN
        end

        def check_addresses_number
            unless addresses_count_valid?
                errors.add(:base, :addresses_to_short, :count => ADDRESSES_COUNT_MIN)
            end
        end

end
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

UPDATE:

Here is my Users:RegistrationsController, where I am building the addresses associations. Maybe i am building the associations in the place? The #new and #create actions are of particular interest in this snippet:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

include Users::InvitationsHelper
include DeviseHelper
  # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
        @token = params[:invite_token]
        build_resource({})
        set_minimum_password_length
        yield resource if block_given?
        self.resource.addresses.build
        respond_with self.resource

    end

  # POST /resource
  def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        self.resource.addresses.build
        resource.save
        @token = params[:invite_token]

    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
            if @token != nil
                sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                handle_invite_accept(@token)
            else
                if resource.active_for_authentication?
                    set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
                    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
                else
                    set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
                    expire_data_after_sign_in!
                    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
                end
            end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

This is what `#configure_sign_up_params` looks like:

```
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
            :addresses_attributes => [:name, :country, :city, :address, :postal_code, :_destroy]])
  end
```

Also, I just noticed that when I fill in one of the address fields, and submit the form, on the the user_id, created_at, and updated_at fields are being filled in for the address record. But the attributes are being passed into the params hash when the form is submitted.

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-08-09 20:37:48 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4LSGSYdk/BwPDBC+li1btDR3KG3q8u9UrIkiyx9bZt+G+pV1o4uJhUZpa8UaqXnqSBva+aayrZ+sOk0vD+LO4g==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Matthew", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "addresses_attributes"=>{"1470789454196"=>{"name"=>"lkjhslkjdhf", "city"=>"lkjhslkdjfh", "address"=>"lkhsldkjhf", "postal_code"=>"lkjhslkdjhf", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$v5n9eoBvN1Z./tYeujdyJOcNbC3x67G5JnGeqXPxkTnHQLff2gqR."], ["name", "Matthew"], ["created_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.679617"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.679617"]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 6], ["created_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.681451"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.681451"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.684863"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.684863"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 00:37:48.685680"], ["id", 6]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 199ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-08-09 20:37:48 -0400
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Rendered layouts/_nav_links_for_auth.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered visitors/_teamsnap_member_modal.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 52.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

And when I look for the last created user in the rails console I get this:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.last.addresses
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Address Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 6]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Address id: 7, name: nil, country: nil, city: nil, address: nil, postal_code: nil, user_id: 6, created_at: "2016-08-10 00:37:48", updated_at: "2016-08-10 00:37:48">]>
```

UPDATE 2:

This was a shot in the dark, and I'm not sure why this would fix the problem. Anyway, I removed `attr_accessor :addresses_attributes`
from the user model. And it solved my problem. That line of code didn't make sense and I don't need it. After removing it, the address object create began working as expected.

Comment: Your `validate...do` is an odd construction. Try: `validate :check_addresses_number` instead. Also: `all_blank` will only be called if there is an address to check. Can you show us the form you use to add the addresses? and look in your server logs to give us an example of the `params` hash that comes through with addresses in them? Also: have you checked if the address is in your `permit/require` section in your controller?

Comment: The objects are being created just fine. I'm just struggling to add validation for the creation of at least 1 nested objected on submission. I'll post more information

Comment: ACtually, I just noticed the address objects aren't being created properly...they were about a week ago. And now they are not!

Comment: `attr_accessor :addresses_attributes` oh yeah, that's weird, you definitely don't need that and it would interfere with what `accepts_nested-attributes` creates on your model for you.

Comment: So it makes sense that it would cause trouble, cool. Thanks for all the good suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

**Validation of nested attributes:**

To validate nested attributes use validation rules in your model to which it belongs to. You don't need to define in the model which accepts the attributes.
Just use `accept_nested_attributes_for :modelname` in model that uses nested attributes and in the main model use `validates_presence_of :attribute` in to the model where attributes belongs to.

Comment: This won't help. The author is trying to validate that there *is* an address, not that an attribute *on* the address is valid... this definitely is something that needs to be done from the parent object